# Background Image with .SCSS in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-image

I have followed advice from other topics but can't get it to work. I want to set a background image.

my scss file is custom.css.scss and code is body

`{ background-image: url("back.png"); }`

`back.png` is located in `app/assets/images`

`custom.css.scss` is located in `app/stylesheets`

i have no problem getting back.png to work through the asset pipeline in my html pages with

`<%= image_tag "back.png" %>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#SCSS
body {
  background: {
     image: asset_url("back.png");
  }
}

#SASS
body
  background:
    image: asset-url("back.png")
```

---

I would strongly recommend using [`SASS`](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) over `SCSS`.

The simple difference is that SASS doesn't have any `semicolons` or `brackets`. Other functionality is the same.

--

Although `asset_path` works, we've found it much more effective to use [`asset-url`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass) ([`asset_url`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_url) in `SCSS`)

Comment: Nice, thanks for letting me know! To save others the hassle, you may wish to accept the answer; make sure you look at `SASS` too - it's highly recommended

Answer (score 3):

use it with the asset pipeline

```
body { background-image: url(asset-path('back.png', image)); }
```

more functions at the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/petebrowne/sprockets-sass/master/Sprockets/Sass/Functions)

Comment: Might be outdated now. What works for me is removing the `image` part: `body { background-image: url(asset-path('back.png')); }`